# How come ambient occlusion shadows not showing in Blender Render-Render?

Tags: texturing

[image]

How come the ambient occlusion I see in the 3D viewport is different from the render?

Or is it that they must be baked to view them in the render?

Comment: What material are you using on cube and plane? Is it an emission shader?

Comment: no, the default one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The viewport AO feature is fairly new, and has extra options that allow it to be overdriven and produce extra high ao for the the edges between the cube and the plane. An open 90 degree corner like that should not really produce much ambient occlusion because it's too open for much occlusion to happen. The older AO feature in the World panel is actually working more accurately than the viewport tool.

You can actually drive the AO value high by manually typing in a value higher than 1.0.

In my example I've added an inset edge in the middle of the cube. You can now see more clearly the difference between the Env light only shadow and the addition of the AO shadow. Note that the surface does not get brigher with the AO set to Multiply.

[image]

Comment: makes sence, makes sence.

Comment: You can use AO in Add mode which does brighten the surface as if lighting it, but I don't find it very useful in that mode.

Comment: it you use AO in add mode, it looks like it acts the same way as environmental lighting, but in multiply mode I can see a difference.

Comment: So that must mean, to view the other AO settings in my render (like distance, attenuation, samples) I have to bake it?

Comment: I think the viewport AO settings only affect the viewport. If you bake the AO I think you would get the settings from the World panel AO.

Answer (score 2):

Just some technical info to add add to the above answer.

The viewport ambient occlusion is not true "ambient occlusion" per-se but actually SSAO which stands for [Screen Space Ambient Occlusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_space_ambient_occlusion)

It shares some common points, a similar visual appearance, but all in all are fundamentally different. SSAO is at it base optimized for being very fast and computationally inexpensive, suited for real time rendering like game engines or the viewport OpenGL rendering, unlike true ambient occlusion which is slower even though it is still relatively inexpensive compared to raytracing a scene.

It uses only the Z-Depth buffer and some clever math to achieve a visually similar aproximation of the effect of true AO at the expense of accuracy.

[image: SSAO]

Comment: I wonder if I can get a similar shadow to ambient occlusion without using ambient occlusion. Maybe some fancy node setup or lamp setup. But thank you for your input. Hinting at a node setup using math nodes and z-depth?