# Why does EEVEE's Ambient Occlusion darken vertical surfaces seen obliquely in reflection planes? Is there a way to make it not do that?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection

I've been trying to get a reflection plane working in a scene, but something weird is going on when I enable Ambient Occlusion in the scene properties. Without AO, it looks okay...

[image: Ambient Occlusion disabled]

...but if I enable AO, all reflected vertical surfaces that are oblique to the point of view darken significantly:

[image: Ambient Occlusion enabled]

(The sides of the bookcase adjacent to the mirror, the right side of the cube, and the left side of the cylinder.) However, as I pan the camera to either side, the reflected surfaces lighten as they become less oblique:

[image: Camera panned to the left, with no other changes]

(Similarly, surfaces that were more orthogonal to the camera direction darken as they become more oblique.) The weird thing is, it only seems to be vertical surfaces that darken in this way; horizontal surfaces look as expected even when they're nearly parallel to the camera direction:

[image: Identical cylinders with different rotations]

Why does this happen, and is there a way I can prevent it from happening? I've tried altering the various Ambient Occlusion parameters, but the changes that get rid of the unwanted effect also get rid of the ambient occlusion that I *do* want.

(The darkening also occurs in full Eevee renders; it's not just in LookDev mode.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58006/how-come-ambient-occlusion-shadows-not-showing-in-blender-render-render/58016#58016

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure it actually addresses my questions. Why does it only occur on **vertical** surfaces reflected in a reflection plane, not horizontal ones? And more importantly, how do I stop it from happening without killing the AO that I do want?

Comment: I don't have an accurate answer, SSAO is an approximation based on a depth calculation, it has inherent limitations and cases where it just doesn't work well